# I want to create a function that prints a message 5 times in assembly language, but my code is running infinitely, so how can I fix it?

Tags: function, loops, assembly, return, system-calls

This is my code:

```
global _start

section .text

_start:
mov rbx, 5

func:
mov rax, 1
mov rdi, 1
mov rsi, msg
mov rdx, msglen
syscall
dec rbx
call func

mov rax, 60
mov rdi, 0
syscall

section .rodata
msg: db "Hello", 10
msglen: equ $ - msg
```

Note that I am new in assembly langauge and it is my first time doing a function so I don't know if the above code is the correct format even

I tried ret but I got an Segmentation Fault (core dump) error, and when I searched it said that if I am linking with ld (which I am doing) that I should not use ret and use syscall, which made the function run but now my new problme is limiting the loop to x times

Comment: `call func` should be `jnz func`.